# TeamCity Agents 64-bit fail to start

Tags: agent, teamcity-9.0, java-service-wrapper

I am trying to get the 64-bit version of a TeamCity (9.1.1) agent running.  I can install the service, but as soon as I start it, I get the following in the wrapper.log:

```
ERROR  | wrapper  | .... | Stdout pipe creation failed
ERROR  | wrapper  | .... | The TeamCity Build Agent service was launched, but failed to start.
```

I can't find any other log entries providing info regarding this.

Any suggestions?  I literally only found two similar posts online, which makes me think it is more related to the Java service wrapper than TeamCity...

(Update: The 64-bit version is required to execute tests specific to a 64-bit version of a built assembly)

Comment: Have you found out what it was?

Comment: Issue logged with Jetbrains:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-45942

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error. First make sure build agent is visible in "Services" panel in Windows. I did following steps and problem solved

- Open command prompt
- run /bin/service.uninstall.bat
- run /bin/service.install.bat
- run /bin/service.start.bat

I have also encountered that in TeamCity 9.1.7 if you install additional build agent through MSI installer and install "Windows Service" component, it replaces the previously installed build agent. I had to do workaround to solve that problem as well.

Comment: The issue is not installing more than one agent; the issue is that I cannot get a (successfully) installed 64-bit agent to start. The agent is visible as a service in the service console, but it fails during startup

Comment: /bin/service.install.bat and /bin/service.install.bat target the 32-bit version if I am not mistaken (look at the EXE it references)

Comment: Why do you want to install 64 bit agent? I think 64-bit JVM on server is fine. But if you still want to do that.
In service.install.bat you can replace this  "..\launcher\bin\TeamCityAgentService-windows-x86-32.exe -i ../conf/wrapper.conf" by "..\launcher\bin\TeamCityAgentService-windows-x86-64.exe -i ../conf/wrapper.conf".
You can cross check if this file "<agentHomeDir>\launcher\bin\TeamCityAgentService-windows-x86-64.exe" exists.
You may also have to upgrade JRE on build agent to 64-bit. It is located in <agentHomeDir>\jre

Comment: I need to be able to execute tests specific to 64-bit assemblies

Comment: Yes, it's not working - according to Jetbrains there is an issue logged for this at
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FTW-45942

Comment: Go to <buildAgentHome>\logs and check these log files
wrapper
launcher
teamcity-agent

It will tell you what is exact problem with agent

Comment: The log entries are the ones in my original question

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.
Go to agent builder folder. In my case "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\bin"

execute "agent stop"
and "agent start"